# Coordinate transformation for coordinate basis vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors

Consdier a coordinate transformation $x^a\rightarrow x^{'a}$ on a manifold with coordinate basis vectors $\textbf{e}_a$ and $\textbf{e}^{'}_a$.

The relationship between the coordinate basis vectors $\textbf{e}_a$ and $\textbf{e}^{'}_a$ is given by
$$\textbf{e}^{'}_b=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^{'b}} \textbf{e}_a.$$

One way to prove this is to consider the infinitesimal displacement vector $d\textbf{s}$ between two points on the manifold given by $$d\textbf{s}=dx^a\textbf{e}_a=dx^{'b}\textbf{e}^{'}_{b}$$ and using $dx^a=(\partial x^a/\partial x^{'b})dx^{'b}$ to get

$${\partial x^a\over \partial x^{'b}}dx^{'b}\textbf{e}_a=dx^{'b}\textbf{e}^{'}_b$$
$$({\partial x^a\over \partial x^{'b}}\textbf{e}_a-\textbf{e}^{'}_b)dx^{'b}=0$$
from where we get $$\textbf{e}^{'}_b=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^{'b}} \textbf{e}_a.$$

The jump from the second last equation to the last equation confuses me. All the second last equation says is that the sum $({\partial x^a\over \partial x^{'b}}\textbf{e}_a-\textbf{e}^{'}_b)dx^{'b}$ sums to zero. How can we say that $dx^{'b}$ is non-zero and hence $({\partial x^a\over \partial x^{'b}}\textbf{e}_a-\textbf{e}^{'}_b)=0$?

Also, even if $dx^{'b}$ is non zero, the terms $({\partial x^a\over \partial x^{'b}}\textbf{e}_a-\textbf{e}^{'}_b)$ need not necessarily all equal to zero for the sum $({\partial x^a\over \partial x^{'b}}\textbf{e}_a-\textbf{e}^{'}_b)dx^{'b}$ to sum to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the $\{dx^{'b}\}_{b=1}^n$ are linearly independent differential forms; in fact they form a basis for the cotangent space of the manifold, moreover they are the dual basis to $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'b}}\right\}_{n=1}^n$. So, if you have a linear combination of them which vanishes
\begin{align}
\sum_{b=1}^nA_b\, dx^{'b} &= 0
\end{align}
then it follows that each of the coefficients $A_b$ is zero (by definition of linear independence).